# Webmail with option to change password for email account?

Tags: email, looking-for-a-script, webmail

Been testing out different webmail options to use (so far AfterLogic, Horde) And it seems that there is no options to change password for user.

It's really bad thing that i have to go to server and manually change passwords for users.

Is there any webmail solution that will allow me to change password, that also changes on server (as client).

Or is it server setting i must use before? Or it is not possible?

EDIT: **Note that i have cPanel host.**

Comment: this isn't a programming question, is it?

Comment: I wish i could tell you :) I'm hopping it's not and i'll be able to find webmail where i can do that.

Comment: I'm interested in something like this as well. You can rule out squirrelmail and roundcude.

Comment: @John Conde So far i found out that you can provide way to change users password on cPanel it's like http://your-host.tld/webmail but as it's uncool it also looks ugly.

Answer (score 1):

On my webmail setup ([Squirrelmail](http://www.squirrelmail.org/) with [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/)), the user accounts are actually managed on the Dovecot side of the street.

While it's not impossible to have a webmail client that would have access to these user accounts, you would have to find a client with support for your type of email server. Apparently SquirrelMail 1.5 and above have this ability, but only through an extra daemon.

This is the closest I've come to finding a solution to the issue you mentioned, and I'll update my answer if I get any closer.

Comment: I found a php class that possibly could extend any webmail client and display cpanels change password fields there, but i have to test it before i can say anything

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using Webmail via Cpanel.

When logging into example.com/webmail, before you are 'auto-loaded' into the specific webmail program (such as Roundcube or Horde), there is an option at the bottom to change your password.

The only trick is that the users first have to login successfully to webmail before changing their password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want self-hosted, which would rule out Google Apps? You can change the password for the user in that though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible

I don't know cpanel well so below comments are generalised

You have three separate applications interacting (or not interacting). Your control panel which will configure an imap server likely Dovecot or Courier. You then have a webmail app communicating with the server over IMAP, just as a desktop mail client would. The imap protocol does not have any provision to change passwords. There may be some webmail clients that have special integration with the mail server (mailenable pro V5 on a windows sevrer) or via special plugins (SquirrelMail ?) but in his case you will  have two applications both trying to configure the mail server, it's likely that when services are restarted the control panel would overwrite the passwords with it's own records.